# MySQL Cluster: cannot start the management node

Tags: mysql

When I try to start the management node of MySQL Cluster on Windows platform, I get the following error:

> Could neither create or open key 'SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\EventLog\Application\MySQL Cluster Management Server', error: 5
>   Failed to setup event logging

Could someone explain this to me?

Comment: if "error: 5" is the windows system error 5 then this means `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED` (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681381%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) so it seems that the user as not the necessary permissions to do something (creating or open the key). you can check with regedit if the key exists and if the user has the permissions to manipulate the key.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you can ignore this error as the `mysqld` should still start up.

However, in trying to reproduce the problem, I've found a glitch in the quick start guide for Windows, a "-" (the standard dash, ASCII 45) has been substituted with a "–" (the long dash, ASCII 150), the correct options for the MySQL client should be "-h 127.0.0.1 -P5000 -u root".

Try this out (i.e. type out the option rather than cutting and pasting from the quick start guide).

With the wrong character, the MySQL client refuses to connect to the MySQL daemon which could give the impression that the MySQL daemon process (`mysqld`) wasn't running correctly.